# How can style the element that I bold in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Problem on how to style the append element in javascript. How can style the elemnt that i bold in javascript?  try to style it in the javascript but failed to.  Can someone help me? How can style this part?

```
                            let contents = document.createElement('div');
                            contents.innerHTML = **val1.mail_no + ' - ' + val1.mail_subject;**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by updating `style` attribute of `contents`:

```
contents.style.fontWeight='bold'
```

Comment: because i want styles differently for each one

Comment: different styles means?

Comment: i am still not clear. What do you want to say by adding code in comment

Comment: So you want to style this `val1.mail_typle_value + val1.mail_serial_no + ' - ' + val1.mail_subject;` ?

Comment: yes especailly the mail_type value consist of diffent mail type (Incoming, Outcoming). I want each mail type consist of different color border. now i got another problem i want to add link . I know it can be insert like this (val1.mail_typle_value + val1.mail_serial_no + ' - ' + val1.mail_url ) but i dont want show the full link of the url . url value is val1.mail_url. How can make it work?

Comment: For mail type you can create it as different classes and the give that class to contents like this : contents.className=val1.mail_type

Comment: For link, you need to create an anchor tag so you can do like this: contents.innerHTML = '<a href="'+val1.mail_url+'">val1.mail_serial_no + ' - ' + val1.mail_subject+</a>;

Comment: If want to style append(‘${dropOptions.label}’) how to style it.                                  document.getElementById(`agency_${agoptions.ag_id}_${agoptions.ad_id}`).append(`${*dropOptions.label}’)

Comment: wrap it with an element like `span` give a class or style in it. `document.getElementById(agency_${agoptions.ag_id}_${agoptions.ad_id}).append(\`<span class="styleClass" style="your style">${*dropOptions.label}</span>\`)`

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById(`agency_${agoptions.ag_id}_${agoptions.ad_id}`).appendChild(contents).style.fontWeight = "900";

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple of ways you can try

```js
document.getElementById('one').innerHTML = '<b> Show as bold </b>';


document.getElementById('two').innerHTML = '<span style="font-weight: bold;"> bold again </span>';
```

```html
<div id="one">x</div>

<div id="two">y</div>
```

Comment: @tingtingjoanaling, Try some thing like (have changed to template string with empty checks) ```if (key1 != "more_url") {
  let contents = document.createElement("div");
  contents.innerHTML = `<p class="text-center" style="font-weight: bold;">${
    val1.mail_type_value || "na"
  } ${val1.mail_serial_no || "na"}  - ${val1.mail_subject || "na"} </p>`;
  document
    .getElementById(`agency_${agoptions.ag_id}_${agoptions.ad_id}`)
    .appendChild(contents);
}```

Answer (score 0):

> first of all try to avoid using javascript to style elements, but if
> you have to here is how to do it

1. method 1:
   declare a class in css

   .bold{font-weight:bold;}

then add

```
document.getElementById("id of element").classList.add("bold");
```

2. method 2:

   document.getElementById("id of element").style.fontWeight="bold";

Comment: plese use a codepen for a visual display of your code